# How do I tell QListView to resize to fit?

Tags: qt, qlistview

I have a QListView and have assigned a model and a delegate. I am using it to display images in a horizontal bar as below

[image]

On a user event, data is updated in the model. One such event causes the width of the images to be reduced like below(#4).

[image]

I emit a dataChanged on the corresponding index and only the concerned widget is repainted. Because of this, there is a gap between #4 and #5 which does not get filled. I am thinking that there must be a way to refresh all visible rows - but am unable to find it.

I tried the following, but they do not work:

```
1. viewport()->updateGeometries()

2. viewport()->update()

3. I tried changing the width to see if it refreshes
    int curWidth = mp_mylistview->width();
    this->mp_mylistview->setFixedWidth(curWidth + 1);
    this->mp_mylistview->setFixedWidth(curWidth);
```

Any suggestions?

Note: The above images are samples for illustration and not the originals. If you need code, I will need to filter out confidential information before posting it.

Comment: Did you try to set [QListView::resizeMode](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qlistview.html#resizeMode-prop) to `QListView::Adjust` and [QListView::uniformItemSizes](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qlistview.html#uniformItemSizes-prop) to `false`?

Comment: Yes. resizeMode is set to Adjust. uniformItemSizes - I have not changed(defaults to false). I am able to see items of differing sizes.

Comment: Did you implement the minimum size hint method in the widgets?

Comment: @Jay No. I have not. the issue seems to be with the spacing between the widgets and not with the size of the widget - as the selection shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to do was to `emit layoutChanged()` as a follow up to the `dataChanged()`.