# How to force QAbstractItemView recalculate items sizeHints

Tags: qt, qlistview, qsplitter

I have QListView and QTabWidget inside QSplitter. QListView is using custom model and custom delegates. In delegate I reimplemented paint and sizeHint methods. But when I resize view - height of elements doesn't recalculated. How can I fix it?
Sample images:

[image: Before resizing][image: After resizing]

In google I found that it is possible to [emit layoutChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutChanged) from the model, but I want only current view to be updated, because content of model doesn't change.

Delegate code:

```
void ChatItemDelegate::paint( QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    painter->save();

    ChatItem *item = static_cast< ChatItem * >( index.internalPointer() );
    QTextDocument doc;

    doc.setHtml( item->htmlText() );
    doc.setTextWidth( option.rect.width() );

    QRect clip( 0, 0, option.rect.width(), option.rect.height() );
    painter->translate( option.rect.topLeft() );

    QColor bgColor = index.row() % 2 ? QColor( 255, 0, 0, 40 ) : QColor( 0, 255, 0, 40 );
    painter->fillRect( clip, bgColor );
    doc.drawContents( painter, clip );

    qDebug() << "paint: " << option.rect.width() << " idx: " << index.row();

    painter->restore();
}

QSize ChatItemDelegate::sizeHint( const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    ChatItem *item = static_cast< ChatItem * >( index.internalPointer() );
    QTextDocument doc;

    doc.setHtml( item->htmlText() );
    doc.setTextWidth( option.rect.width() );

    qDebug() << "hint:  " << option.rect.width() << " idx: " << index.row();

    return doc.size().toSize();
}
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563499/how-do-i-tell-qlistview-to-resize-to-fit?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging in Qt source code, I found that [scheduleDelayedItemsLayout()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#scheduleDelayedItemsLayout) function is solving the issue on my side.

Comment: Thank you, I've been racking my brain for a while trying to sort this issue. I added this in my view's resizeEvent and my delegates suddenly started resizing themselves properly.

Answer (score 2):

Experiencing the same issue in November 2017...

The only way I found to resolve it is this ugly hack :

```
   QSize size = listView->viewport()->size();
   size.setHeight(size.height()+1);
   listView->viewport()->resize(size);

   size.setHeight(size.height()-1);
   listView->viewport()->resize(size);
```

It forces a resize on the listview, which itself refreshes its row sizes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess, but does setting your QListView's resize mode help?

```
listView->setResizeMode( QListView::Adjust );
```

Comment: Doesn't helped. Currently I connected to splitterMoved signal of QSplitter and call view->model()->reset() on each sizing. I don't think that it's good, i'll try to test it for a lot of items now.

Comment: view->model()->reset() is mega-slow :(

Comment: @Cris, no way. It's protected. I need same behavior for all views, not only for QListView. From documentation - "Updates the geometry of the child widgets of the view" - I don't have child widgets.

Comment: I have a similar problem when using QTreeView and `reset` leads to the expansion states also getting reset, i.e., everything gets collapsed. `updateGeometries` has no effect for some reason even though I manually get and print the `Qt::SizeHintRole` before calling it. Calling `scheduleDelayedItemsLayout` does indeed work!

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions worked for me but this did:

```
listView->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
listView->setViewMode(QListView::ListMode);
```

Comment: How to you recover a scroll bar position?

Comment: In my case I did: `list->scrollTo(list->currentIndex(),QAbstractItemView::PositionAtCenter);`. But you can jump to any other index if you wish.

Comment: And when you did it? On a splitter event? You can just reset a model to get the same effect, but with x2 speed.

Comment: I have a button which changes the size of the items each time the button is pressed. You are correct about the performance issue though. But I was looking for something a little simpler than making reset model functions public and having code for restoring selection.

Answer (score 0):

What about QAbstractItemView::doItemsLayout()

https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#_ZN17QAbstractItemView13doItemsLayoutEv

I have no idea, why this function exists on Qt Sources as a public API, but have not been documented, but seems, it's works fine for me