# How to make QTreeView recalculate row heights?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtreeview, qstyleditemdelegate

There are `QTreeView` with subclassed `QAbstractItemModel` and custom `QStyledItemDelegate`. Custom delegate's `sizeHint` reimplemented and returns calculated correct cell height, considering text wrapping.

So the problem is that cell's height is not changing on column resize. How to force `QTreeView` to recalcualte heights of his cells? I can use signal `QHeaderView::sectionResized` to detect cell resize, but how to make `QTreeView` do cell heights resize?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force QAbstractItemView recalculate items sizeHints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444558/how-to-force-qabstractitemview-recalculate-items-sizehints)